# Math functions in OMNet++

Tags: omnet++

Are there any libraries for math functions accessible from OMNet++ coding environment? I want to compute normal distribution for matrix inputs. This will entail computing exponential, logarithmic, matrix operations (multiply and add).

Is there predefined libraries I could use?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are no dedicated math libraries in `OMNeT++`. However, `OMNeT++` uses C++, so you can use **any of C++ math libraries**. For example, you can use [IT++](http://itpp.sourceforge.net/4.3.1/) to compute matrix operations in code of your simulation.